# xterm is calling .cshrc twice

Tags: xterm, tcsh, csh

I'm running ubuntu 18.04,     I've asked this question on askubuntu, but got no response, so I thought I'd ask on a different forum, hoping for a different readership.  I do know that the same problem happens with ubuntu 16.04.   I'd like to know how to fix this, or at least if this happens more generally, i.e., with other versions of linux.

The following command

```
xterm -e ' tcsh'
```

calls my .cshrc file twice.    But this command calls it once

```
xterm -e 'tcsh'
```

Same thing with

```
xterm -e 'cd `pwd`;tcsh'
```

Obviously, the only difference between the first call and the other two calls is the space.    Why would a space make such a difference?

To test this out, I'm using this MWE version of .cshrc

```
#/bin/tcsh
echo called from cshrc
```

The same problem happens with

```
xterm -e " csh"
```

Thanks for any suggestions about how to fix this!

Answer (score 2):

Guess: The space at the beginning means there is no command to call, so `xterm` tries to interpret this as a shell script, calls your standard shell (which apparently also reads `.cshrc`) with `tcsh` as an argument, which then calls `tcsh`, which reads `.cshrc` again.

You can verify that this is indeed what happens by using `strace`.

You "fix" this by not using a space at the beginning.

Comment: Or maybe by simply omitting `-e tcsh` completely